# VB.NET no recibe respuesta de PostgreSQL 9.3 al insertar registro duplicado

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

He migrado de PostgreSQL 8.3 a PostgreSQL 9.3 para poder usar las mejoras implementadas en esta versión. Con la versión 8.2 no tenía problemas para controlar los errores al intentar insertar un registro duplicado con clave única ya que el programa (vb.net de Visual Studio 2013) recibía mensaje de PostgreSQL y actuaba en consecuencia con una claúsula `TRY...CATCH`. Pero desde que he migrado a 9.3, a la hora de hacer un `insert`, el programa se queda a la espera de recibir alguún mensaje de PostgreSQL 9.3 y no continúa. Os adjunto código de ejemplo:

```vb
Public Sub EjecutaComando(ByVal StringSql As String)
    'Procedure básico para ejecutar Insert i Updates sin tenerlas que implementar en cada uno de los procesos
    Dim data As New NpgsqlCommand
    data.Connection = MiConexio
    data.CommandText = StringSql
    Try
        AbrirConexion()
        data.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        nada()
    Finally
        CerrarConexion()
        data.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Si la sentencia es un `insert` contra una tabla con clave única, el código se queda parado en `data.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Ejecuto la consulta desde *PgAdmin* y me retorna un mensaje de error de `duplicate Key`. La versión *Npgsql* que utilizo es `2.012.0`.

¿Alguien me puede iluminar dónde está el problema?

Comment: No trabajo habitualmente con PosgreSQL, pero confiar la validación de los datos a un `try/catch` me parece un error de diseño. Deberiás asegurarte de que no existe una clave duplicada antes de enviar los datos en mi opinión.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, y ciertamente para solucionar el problema realizo una verificacion previa sobre la tabla, pero mi consulta sigue siendo la misma, porque con la versión 8.2 recibia mensaje de error y en la 9.3 no, piensa que la lógica de programación muchas veces damos por echo que vamos a intentar insertar claves duplicadas y que por defectno no queremos hacer nada, esa es una casuistica a tener en cuenta. está bien verificar antes pero a veces no lo necesitamos como es mi caso.

Comment: Si,por supuesto Xavier. Mi comentario solo era una sugerencia, pero la pregunta que realizas es completamente válida, espero que alguien pueda responderte.En mi caso, como ya dije, no trabajo con PostgreSQL, asi que lamentablemente no puedo ayudarte. :)

Comment: @sstan, el codigo es tan simple que es el que he colocado en mi pregunta, tan solo le paso como parametro la instrucción insert, la instrucción insert es muy básica y no hago transac ya que la logica es abrir conexion, ejecutar insert cerrar conexión, todo muy simple.{ connprov.EjecutaComando("insert into t_descriptor_cadena (retall,valors,descriptor,cadena) values('" & clau & "','" & taulaOCR.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & taulaOCR.Rows(i).Item(2) & "','" & CadenaOCR & "')")}

Comment: @sstan, ya he realizado la prueba que comentas, en concreto debugando la aplicación, cojo el contenido del string de la consulta y la ejecuto en pgAdmin, y me muestra un error de intento de violación de clave única por lo que en ese momento no hay ningún bloqueo. Ya te digo que he realizado mil y una pruebas y no quiero ni puedo volver a la versión anterior de postgresql. Gracias por tu interes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019017/inserting-a-duplicate-record-using-npgsql), tu problema es definitivamente un defecto en la versión de Npsql que usas (2.0.12.0).

Traduciendo una parte de la referencia:

> Nos acabamos de dar cuenta que Npgsql tiene un problema a la hora de manejar los mensajes de error provenientes de PostgreSQL 9.3.x [...] Estamos trabajando en producir una nueva versión 2.0.12 estable con la corrección.

En tu caso, ya que la versión 2.x es ya un tanto antigua, te sugiero de poner tu Npsql al día con [una de las versiones disponibles más recientes](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases) y eso debería arreglar tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de actualizar npgsql 3.2.1 y he recompilado la aplicación, hasta mañana no sabre los resultados pero con la información que me acabas de aportar me has dado la luz. thank you very much